# Changing string to date format

Tags: database, sqlite

Is there a way I can change a string value "01/01/20" to a date format of dd-mm-yyyy which is 01-01-2020 in SQLite? Or a way I can use strftime(%d%m%y,date) on a string value?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `strftime()` because this function operates only on dates of the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

In your case you must use string functions and concatenation:

```
substr(date, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2) || '-20' || substr(date, -2)
```

Note that it would be better to save the dates in the table with the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.
If you do then it is easy to format them as you want:

```
strftime('%d-%m-%Y', date)
```